# Itertool.product at to string

Tags: python-3.x, python-itertools

Hi I starting learning python.

I have to do a small work to generate password using itertool. the only thing I don't understand how to convert this result :

> itertools.product object at 0x03493BE8

to something readeable.

How can I convert it to get a string or something similar ?
 Here is my code :

```
  for CharLength in range(12):
        words= (itertools.product(Alphabet, repeat=CharLength))
        print(words)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itertools.product()` returns a generator.
To print them you can use the * operator.

```
for char_len in range(12):
    words = itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=char_len)
    print(*words)
```

Comment: Thanx for your help, do you know how I can convert it to have a string from each return ?

Comment: In such a case what you can do is `[''.join(word) for word in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=char_len)]`

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.product` returns a generator object. If you wish, you could go over it and convert it to a list so it's easier to view its contents, e.g. by using a list comprehension:

```
words = [w for w in itertools.product(Alphabet, repeat=CharLength)]
```